# Some genres not recognized by Spotify Search API

Tags: web, parameters, spotify

I am trying to use Spotify's search API to get a list of artists by passing a specific genre. Some genres yield results ([example](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item?q=genre%3Arock&type=artist)), however some don't for some reason ([example](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item?q=genre%3Aacoustic&type=artist)). They are both on Spotify's list of supported genres ([here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-available-genre-seeds?)). Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are genre seeds, not available genres in the search engine. They are just different.

For example, the genre "pop-rock" is a valid genre for searching ([proof](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-search-item/?q=genre%3Apop-rock&type=artist#complete)) but it isn't listed in the genre seeds.

Comment: How do I get a list of valid genres for searching? The page that shows allowed parameters for searching linked to the list of genre seeds, so they should work according to that.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to get such a list is query all Spotify artists and insert every new genre in a list. There is no "get all genres" endpoint in their API. But, luckly, there is a webpage that did this: http://everynoise.com/everynoise1d.cgi?scope=all

Comment: Thanks for the help.